# What operations is this set closed under? The set of all $\{(a,b) : (a,b) \in \Bbb{Z}^2, \gcd(a,b) \neq 1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, semigroups

Let $S = \{(a,b): a,b \in \Bbb{Z}, \gcd(a,b) \neq 1 \}$.

Under what binary operations is $S$ closed (that we can come up with)?

I came up with the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
(a,b)(c,d) = \\
 &(1) \ \  (ac, bd) \\
 &(2) \ \  (ad, bc) \\
 &\dots etc. \\
 &(3) \ \ (ac - bd, ad + bc) \\
 &(4) \ \ (lcm(ac), lcm(bd)) \\
 &(5) \ \ (gcd(ac - bd, ad +bc), gcd(ac+bd, ad-bc))
\end{align*}
$$

$(5)$ I'm not sure of, but you get the idea.  What other expressible binary operations is $S$ closed under?